# What if a scale factor is less than 0 in a dilation?

Tags: terminology, isometry

If I have a triangle lets say, $\triangle ABC$ and the graph says to apply the dilation $D$ to the polygon with the vertices:

$D: (x, y) \longrightarrow (-2x, -2y)$

$A(2,1), B(2,3), C(5,1)$

Here...

$k < 0$

The shape is then rotated by 180 degrees, and the dilation happens. But...

> Is it really a dilation if $k<0$?

Comment: Don't think of the operation as involving a $180^\circ$ rotation. Rather, think of the dilated points as having *passed through* the center of dilation. In particular, your dilation $D$ sends a point through the origin to a point twice as far from the origin, but on the opposite side. (So, to answer your question: Yes, the operation is really a dilation if $k<0$.)